# Drawing overlapping shapes in drawRect with different color causes edge-bleeding when anti-aliassing is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have a problem when drawing to equal shapes with a different color that overlap. When enabling anti-aliassing the transparent pixels that get generated bleed through and causes the artifacts as in [this image](http://cl.ly/image/2k3e2E1c2I3d). The sequence her is drawing a red circle, drawing a blue triangle and then drawing a red triangle.

This problem is solvable by disabling anti-aliassing but the outcome are ugly jagged edges.

Are there for instance solutions where I can retro-actively anti-alias the graphic context or render to an image and anti-alias on that image. Or anything else that can help me draw overlapping shapes with crisp edges.

Here is the code to recreate the problem

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(currentContext, rect);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(currentContext, YES);

//// Color Declarations
UIColor* color = [UIColor redColor];
UIColor* color2= [UIColor blueColor];

//// Oval Drawing
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: rect];
[color setFill];
[ovalPath fill];

//// triangle Drawing
UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[trianglePath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, rect.size.height)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[trianglePath closePath];
[color2 setFill];
[trianglePath fill];

[color setFill];
[trianglePath fill];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with drawRect, you're basically drawing on an image, and each draw method renders over the previous one. There is no culling.

To really resolve the issue, you may wish to use OpenGL, where there's only one render pass, so hidden objects aren't rendered.

Comment: Thanks, I set up the same drawing in openGL and it solves my problem, even with multisampling enabled there is visible no edge bleeding.